# Proofs about Jordan outer measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Define Jordan outer measure as a function: $$ j^*: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{\infty\}$$
Where, $$j^*(A) = \inf \left\lbrace\sum_{k=1}^{n} l(I_k) : I_1, .., I_n \ \text{open intervals}, A \subset \cup_{k=1}^n I_k \right\rbrace$$

Prove that $j^*(\emptyset) = 0$, $j^*$ is monotone, finitely subadditive (but not countably).

I think for $j^*(\emptyset)=0$, it is because this can be covered with one interval ($-\epsilon, \epsilon$) for all $\epsilon > 0$ so the length of this interval goes to 0.

Monotone subadditivty was also pretty straightforward, so no need to discuss that here.

I have no idea how to show finitely subadditive though.  I think not having countable subadditivity has something to do with the fact that a set of rational numbers in the interval [0,1] covered by a finite collection of open intervals has $\sum_{k=1}^nl(I_k) \geq 1$

Comment: Please consider being more robust with your usage of TeX. It will improve the quality of your posts and most likely improve responses on it too.

Comment: @rt6 Thanks.  I'll be sure to look into it soon!